# how to have a bold text in opaque environment in css?

Tags: css

Does css support having a background element opaque but the text on it is bold?Or css3 support this only?please give me some reference through which i can acheive the same.

Comment: can you give reference to what you  want

Comment: please put your question along with some sample Demo. so anyone can get idea what you looking for.. As per your question;  Amadan already gave the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.... {
  background-color: #......;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you specify any background that is not transparent (i.e. not a `png` or `gif` or something, and not `rgba(...)`), it'll be opaque.

It will be bold if you specify it should be bold.

I do not see any relationship between two - they should be independent. You can have opaque or non-opaque backgrounds with bold or non-bold texts as you desire.